# É possível criar uma classe sem metadados/ARC no Swift?

Tags: swift, runtime, arc

Qualquer classe do Swift possui 16-bytes (talvez menos em 32bits) de metadados, por exemplo:

```
class Empty {}
print(class_getInstanceSize(Empty.self)) // 16
```

Essas metadados aparentemente é o ARC (o contador de referencias) e informações de tipagem.

Existe como remover esses metadados de alguma forma? Utilizar algo como:

```
@unmanaged()
class Empty {}
```

De tal forma que `print(class_getInstanceSize(Empty.self))` retorne 0.

Eu não posso utilizar `struct` já que no Swift os structs são copiados e preciso que os dados sejam passados como referencia. Aparentemente não há como fazer `*Struct`, ou similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é, até é pouco consumo dos metadados. É o mesmo de quase todas as linguagens ou até menos (principalmente entre as de tipagem dinâmica).

Mesmo em C um objeto alocado dinamicamente, equivalente à classe de Swift, de forma padrão em quase todas as implementações consomem 16 bytes também (em 64 bits) . Há casos de até mais e é possível usar com menos através de alocador customizado. O padrão não usa ARC ou algo parecido e não consegue economizar sem alguma perda em algum ponto.

Swift não foi criada para ser tão flexível e até onde eu sei não tem como mudar a forma de alocação em condições normais.

Claro que tendo os fontes do *runtime* você pode mudar para ter uma versão customizada para seu uso, e será problema seu manter isso.

O objeto [`unmanaged`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unmanaged) ainda precisa de metadados, ainda que não use o ARC.

De fato essa coisa de fazer classes serem fixamente no *heap* é um problema desde que Java inventou isso e C# e Swift copiaram. Ter `struct` ajuda muito e isso é um acerto que Java ainda não tem (prometem há muitos anos que terá). C# tem como passar `struct`s por referência, Swift não, azar.

Você tem toda razão que o ARC é um mecanismo que cobra um preço que muitas vezes não queremos pagar. Swift é um pouco melhor que Java mas não preza muito pela eficiência.

Pelo menos em tudo que li não terá uma solução simples.

Dependendo do caso poderá criar um gerenciador desses objetos.

Cria uma coleção que atenda sua necessidade, uma [lista](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list) por exemplo, e coloca ali os objetos que deseja baseados em `struct`. Haverá o custo dos metadados apenas para a lista e não para cada objeto alocado na lista. Tem caso que resolverá o que quer, tem caso que não.

Outras soluções podem ser pensadas de acordo com o caso concreto.

De qualquer forma, se o objeto é grande os metadados não farão muita diferença, e se for pequeno copiar não será um custo pesado.

Comment: O meu problema é que ja tenho os dados na memoria (imagine um `packed struct` do C dentro de um `[UInt8]` do Swift). Eu queria acessar os dados sem ter que copia-los, porque eles já estão lá esse array, inicialmente algo como: `return Unmanaged<AnyObject>.fromOpaque(self.ptr + (index * self.size)).takeUnretainedValue() as! MeuTipo`. O MeuTipo seria uma classe que teria metodos para acessar cada informação (já que o Swift também não suporta "packed struct", entao daria pra emular). O que quebrou minhas pernas foi esse "padding" de 16bytes.   Vou fazer outra gambiarra para tentar resolver.